# Store instance reference in a for loop with Tween.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, tween.js

I am looping through an array of CSS3DObjects in THREE.JS and want to remove them from the DOM in the context of Tween.js onComplete(). But how do I refer to the dom instance so each Tween instance can tell the dom element to remove itself?

```
for ( var i = 0; i < _tier1Objects.length; i ++ ) {
    new TWEEN.Tween( _tier1Objects[i].position )
        .to( {z: -50}, 1000 )
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out)
        .onComplete( function() {
            scene.remove( [CSS3DObject instance] ); // REMOVE THE THREE JS OBJ INSTANCE
            $([dom element]).remove(); // REMOVE THE HTML DOM ELEMENT VIA JQUERY
            })
        .start();
}
```

Perhaps there's a best practice I'm not aware of here. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example and it worked to get me access to the object instance:

```
function closeTier1Items() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < _tier1Objects.length; i ++ ) {
        new TWEEN.Tween( _tier1Objects[i].position )
            .to( {z: -50}, 1000 )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out)
            .onComplete(
                function(obj){
                    return function(){
                        scene.remove(obj);
                    }
                }( _tier1Objects[i] )
            )
            .start();
    }
}
```

But OUCH that's a bit of a mind bender! Perhaps there's a simpler way to store the object instance??